Coterminal angles that are congruent.
Today I encountered a problem that seems to be inconsistent.
I was asked to provide a set of all angles coterminal to $25^\circ$.
My answer was $$\{n(360^\circ) + 25^\circ \mid n \;\text{is an integer}\}$$
The answer provided was
$$\{n(360^\circ) + 25^\circ\mid n\;\text{is a non-zero integer}\}$$
Which of these is correct?
Edit:
For some added context the definition given is "Two angles are coterminal if their terminal sides coincide when they are both drawn in standard position."
Also the first answer (Mine) is identical (except in the value of the angle), yet later used the second as an answer.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... What's "correct" comes down to whether "co-terminal" has been defined in the given context in such a way to rule-out an angle being co-terminal with itself. I don't doubt some authors disagree about this. (We can't even agree on whether zero is a natural number.) What's the exact definition provided to you? ... For what it's worth, I probably would've given the "integer" answer instead of "non-zero integer".

I was given "Two angles are coterminal if their terminal sides coincide when they are both drawn in standard position." In examples they gave equivalents to my inital answer, later when asked again they gave the second one. I think it might just be some lack of consistency.

Consistency in the same presentation would be nice, but mistakes happen. ... In any case, please add that information to the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)
